# RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I am using a python code for the live sentiment analysis based on twitter.
It should work because there is a tutorial too on youtube, but on my computer, this is the error that I have:

```
File "<ipython-input-2-9dc468222105>", line 1, in <module>
         runfile('C:/Users/marco/Anaconda3/envs/coinlive/social_functions.py',
 wdir='C:/Users/marco/Anaconda3/envs/coinlive')

File "C:\Users\marco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
 line 710, in runfile
         execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\marco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
 line 101, in execfile
         exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/marco/Anaconda3/envs/coinlive/social_functions.py", line 82,
 in <module>
         twitterStream.filter(track=["Donald Trump"])

File "C:\Users\marco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line
 450, in filter
         self._start(async)

File "C:\Users\marco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line
 364, in _start
         self._run()

File "C:\Users\marco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line
 297, in _run
         six.reraise(*exc_info)

File "C:\Users\marco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
         raise value

File "C:\Users\marco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line
 266, in _run
         self._read_loop(resp)

File "C:\Users\marco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line
 327, in _read_loop
         self._data(next_status_obj)

File "C:\Users\marco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line
 300, in _data
         if self.listener.on_data(data) is False:

File "C:/Users/marco/Anaconda3/envs/coinlive/social_functions.py", line 39,
 in on_data
         tweet=" ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", tweet))

File "C:\Users\marco\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 222, in findall
         return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)

TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

I think the error is related to tweepy library and I read many posts but withotu any good result.

This is my code:

```
import time
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json
from textblob import TextBlob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

"# -- coding: utf-8 --"

def calctime(a):
    return time.time()-a

positive=0
negative=0
compound=0

count=0
initime=time.time()
plt.ion()

ckey='R8adMtTxKPXseiFqFcb7XBGJv'
csecret='rkcxNsg8Q09AiVDgh4bn5GXNpsLP0jLwekqIOkrdkwa1K1h9oc'
atoken='232118221-5SPjlFvC22JBRXODNdNWoEDJwvpvaiKoXAazpAHH'
asecret='rzZ1NMxfgK6IYzTuEI0rMvpK04lJj49tiKe1BaST9bmcT'

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self,data):
        global initime
        t=int(calctime(initime))
        all_data=json.loads(data)
        tweet=all_data["text"].encode("utf-8")
        #username=all_data["user"]["screen_name"]
        tweet=" ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", tweet))
        blob=TextBlob(tweet.strip())

        global positive
        global negative     
        global compound  
        global count

        count=count+1
        senti=0
        for sen in blob.sentences:
            senti=senti+sen.sentiment.polarity
            if sen.sentiment.polarity >= 0:
                positive=positive+sen.sentiment.polarity   
            else:
                negative=negative+sen.sentiment.polarity  
        compound=compound+senti        
        print(count)
        print(tweet.strip())
        print(senti)
        print(t)
        print(str(positive) + ' ' + str(negative) + ' ' + str(compound))


        plt.axis([ 0, 70, -20,20])
        plt.xlabel('Time')
        plt.ylabel('Sentiment')
        plt.plot([t],[positive],'go',[t] ,[negative],'ro',[t],[compound],'bo')
        plt.show()
        plt.pause(0.0001)
        if count==200:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def on_error(self,status):
        print(status)


auth=OAuthHandler(ckey,csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken,asecret)

twitterStream=  Stream(auth, listener(count))
twitterStream.filter(track=["Donald Trump"])
```

Comment: Could you attach the full traceback?

Comment: Also, you need to put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (not as a string) as the first or second line in your script

Comment: thx for your interest man, I added the full traceback on the post...

Comment: Have you made sure that you are running the latest version (`pip install --upgrade tweepy`?

Comment: I updated the library, now there is this error: 
  File "C:\Users\marco\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 222, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)

TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding the string

```
tweet=all_data["text"].encode("utf-8")
```

and then try to run re.findall on it:

```
tweet=" ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", tweet))
```

Try without the encode call